# Getting data from JSON file and using it in c#

Tags: c#, json, api, stream

I want to make a program that reads some data from JSON file generated from an API.
Here's an example of that JSON file:

```
{"block4o": {
   "id": 20153910,
   "name": "Block4o",
   "profileIconId": 616,
   "revisionDate": 1408783284000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

What I need to do is to get e.g the id and the name from it.
  Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public void HowToMakeRequestsToHttpBasedServices()
        {
            Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Block4o?api_key=****");
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            downloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloader_OpenReadCompleted);
            downloader.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
        }

        void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                // Continue working with responseStream here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instal Newtonsoft.Json using NuGet and write smth like this:

```
if (e.Error == null)
{
    string text = e.Result;
    var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(text);
}
```

My code use my class Event and get List of Event from JSON string

It is better to user Newtonsoft.Json instead of build-in libraries, because you can't use them is some modern project types(e.g. windows phone app)

------------------------update

You can create class:

```
public class Block
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int profileIconId;
    public int revisionDate;
    public int summonerLevel;
}

public class BlockWrapper
{
    public Block block4o;
}
//...
BlockWrapper blockWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlockWrapper>(text);
```

Comment: I've installed newtonsoft.json from NuGet but can you tell me how to use this "my class Event and get List of Event"? I'm a bit new in c# so excuse me for the question if it's stupid

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/NLe9rcht) When I build the program. It opens a console for a sec and then closes it. What could be the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think, that OpenReadCompletedEventHandler isn't thing, that you need. I'm using DownloadStringCompleted, change event of WebClient object and change handler to DownloadStringCompletedEventHander. I think, that you callback works just for correct opening file

Comment: client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri()) after adding callback

Comment: good luck :) one more idea - there are some problems with cache when you use WebClient. you will see that you change server data, but requester get the same. you can add smth like "?nocache=randomdouble" ot url to avoid it